# VS Code Java debugger arguments

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to use VS Code [debugger plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.javadebugger) to debug.
My program takes some command line arguments in the main method. The debugger plugin says it has support for arguments, but I couldn't figure out how to provide these to the debugger.

I created the `task.json` that it suggested, but if I put the args in the "args" field of the json, it gives an error.

This is my `tasks.json`:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "javac",
"isShellCommand": true,
"showOutput": "always",
"isWatching": true,
"suppressTaskName": true,
  "tasks": [
      {
          "taskName": "build",
          "args": ["-g", "${file}"]
      }
  ]
}
```

and this is my `launch.json`:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Java",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "startupClass": "${fileBasename}",
        "options": [
            "-classpath",
            "${workspaceRoot}:."
        ],
        "jdkPath": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin"
    },
    {
        "name": "Java Console App",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "startupClass": "${fileBasename}",
        "options": [
            "-classpath",
            "\"${fileDirname};.\""
        ],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "jdkPath": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to get the debugger to work for me... Are you able to hit breakpoints atm?

As for passing args, you could try changing your options to be like this:

`"options": [
            "-classpath",
            "${workspaceRoot}:."
            "${fileBasename}", // Or the name of your main class
            "arg1",
            "arg2"
        ],`

Kind of a shot in the dark, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some trial and error on this topic and it appears that if you repeat the `startupClass` in `options` followed by the parameter you want to pass, then the debugger does engage and enter the `main()` of your `startupClass` except that it does so with an extra arguments (name of your `startupClass`).

In my case the `main()` program actually errors out after checking number of parameters (it is only expecting 1), so I can't do much beyond that (don't control source code I'm debugging), but perhaps you can?

Here are the relevant excerpts from my `launch.json`

`"startupClass":"org.my.startupClass"
    ...
    ...
    "options"[
        "-classpath",
        "full/path/where/the/jar/containing/org.my.startupClass/resides;.",
        "org.my.startupClass",
        "arg1",
        "arg2"
         ...
         ...
    ]`

With this `launch.json`, I go to the file I am trying to run (which is one of the `args` to the `main()` of `org.my.startupClass` and hit `F5`, which successfully gets me to a paused debugger inside `main()`. But on examining the args array I see two entries.

If I didn't mention the `startupClass` in the `options` section of `launch.json`, I get the error in debugger console:

`Error: Could not find or load main class arg1`

FYI, I'm on VSCode 1.13.0 and Java Debugger extension 0.1.0.

Taking a closer look at the [source code](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/javaVSCode/blob/0d41f51d742db404e48848ead85a31dfd29a0280/src/client/jdb.ts), it appears that if you passed your `main()` arguments under the args key of launch.json, you would just need to make a one line code change to make it work:

In method `private startProgramInDebugJavaMode()` there is a **place** where you build the arguments to pass to the debugging child process:

`var javaPath = (!this.args.jdkPath || this.args.jdkPath.length === 0) ? "java" : path.join(this.args.jdkPath, "java");
var options = this.args.options;
var args = [-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=${port}].concat(options).concat(this.className);`

 If you appended another `.concat(this.args.args)` to `var arg`, that ought to do it?